# Difference between docker schema v1 and v2 spec and how to find docker image schema?

Tags: image, docker

I have a docker image and want to figure out whether its schema 1 or schema 2 type image and what is the main difference b/w them? I am using [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko) build tool and it fails because of base image with following error.

> unsupported MediaType:
>   "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws"

I did docker inspect but it didn't help and I read about docker [manifest](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/manifest/) but my docker doesn't have manifest subcommand.

Comment: What is the context of that error? What command generates it, at what point, and with what input? We also need to know about your build environment, including what version of the various tools and components you are using.

Comment: The v1 schema was deprecated a while back, but no current build tools should be using this: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/deprecated-schema-v1/